# Possible applications of inequalty with expectation and norm in $R^n$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, inequality, random-variables

Let $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is a norm in  $R^n$. Let  $x_1,\dots,x_N$ are non-necessarily independent Rademacher random variables random variables (variables which are uniform on $\{-1, 1\}$). By $E$ we denote an expectation. There exists a constant $A_{p,q}$ depending only on $p,q$ such that for any vectors $u_1,\dots, u_N\in R^n$ 
$$
\left(E \left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^N x_iu_i\right\Vert^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}\leq A_{p,q} E \left(\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^N x_iu_i\right\Vert^{q}\right)^{\frac 1q},
$$
for all $p,q \in [1, \infty)$.

This is so called restricted Kahane's inequality.

What are the possible applications of this inequality?

Comment: I do not get the equation that you wrote down.  It looks like $$(E(||Z||^p)^{1/p} ) \leq a_p E(||Z||)$$ The summation term does not play a role.

Comment: Where did you come across this inequality and why did the particular resources that used this inequality not show any background how, where and when this is used?

Comment: Thank you, it was a typo--the power of the right side have been missing.